# ADODB Paste Very slow

Tags: excel, adodb, vba

I have a ADODB connection that retrieves 45k rows and 48 columns of data. The query is executed in less than 1 second but the copyformrecordset line is taking more than 15 minutes to execute. Anyone know why it is so slow?

Update: adding `Connection.CursorLocation = adUseClient` moves the delay to the recordset open line and makes the copyfromrecordset almost immediate. I am not sure if that helps narrow down the reason why it still takes 15 mins either way. I have seen other people posting 60k+ rows in just seconds.

```
 Sub HarvestData()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim Connection As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim QT As Excel.QueryTable
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    Dim SQL As String
    Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection
    Set Rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset

'Making the call to the database
    ConnectionString = Myconnectionstringishere

 'The query that is being pulled
    SQL = Sheets("SQL").Range("B13").Value

'This is executing the SQL query
    Connection.Open ConnectionString
    Rs1.Open SQL, Connection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

'This is defining a location for the data to be pasted
    Set Location = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'This is pasting the data
    Location.Range("b2").CopyFromRecordset Rs1

'These are closing the connections I opened
     Rs1.Close
     Connection.Close
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Try to format target cells as text first, like `Cells.NumberFormat = "@" `

Comment: No change, but thanks!

Comment: is the query really executed in 1 sec, or is that just the time to return the first record?  if you just loop over the recordset until you hit EOF how long does that take?  Is this a local datasource?

Comment: I took to long to edit: This line 'Rs1.Open SQL, Connection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly' Executes in under one second and then pasting the first to the last record in 'Location.Range("b2").CopyFromRecordset Rs1' takes 15 minutes. However if I add Connection.CursorLocation = adUseClient it flips so the first line is 15 minutes and the paste takes one second. To just loop over the recordset it takes a little under half that time 6.9 Minutes, to put it in an array it takes 15 minutes again. The datasource is not local.

Comment: So it looks like half your performance problem is getting the records from the database, and the other half is putting them on the worksheet.  You'd have to look at tweaking your SQL to see if you can work on the database performance, and then try a few things on the client-side to see if you can get the data to the sheet more quickly.  That's a *lot* of data though.  You don't mention what database you're using, but you could try a different driver if one's available.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what your SQL Query is but I use this as my paste command...

```
With ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2)              
    rec_QTY = .CopyFromRecordset(Rs1)
End With
```

I dabble in large number of database records ... and this command is usually quite fast. 
Cells(2,2) is the same as Range("B2")

Comment: rec_QTY is just a variable ... its not defined or used anywhere before or after the above statement in my code. Just replace Location.Range("b2").CopyFromRecordset Rs1 with With ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2)              
    rec_QTY = .CopyFromRecordset(Rs1)
End With

Comment: Thanks, but no luck.

Comment: Can you explain why assigning the result of `CopyFromRecordset` (which is ususally the number of records copied) makes the copy faster? Did you benchmark it, or do you have a reference for that claim?

Comment: I didn't bench mark it ,,, but 45k is a relatively small record set in my world.

Comment: I would need to see more of the code and other details like computer specs and version of excel to comment further

Comment: I just tried your paste method (Location.Range("b2").CopyFromRecordset Rs1) on 100,000 records (each record has 65 fields) and it took 7 seconds. I also tried my method ... and it was also 7 seconds. So I think the issue is computer specs or version of excel.